# Method of Steepest Descent

Tags: numerical-methods

I have been given this question from my university to complete and I am having some trouble. The lecturer did not do a very good job of explaining the concept and I could not find any materials online to help so I came here. The question is-

What happens if you apply the method of steepest descent to 
$f(x)=(x_1^2)+(x_2^2)+(x_3^2)$

Thank you.

Comment: @CaveJohnson It does appear this is someone with the same problem, however it has not been answered on that post either